# Unresolved inclusion to everything

Tags: c++, eclipse, inclusion

Well, this strange error occurs in all of my project code files (h and cpp files)
I didn’t change anything before, and all of a sudden during debugging it started to show up:
This is the error I'm talking about:
[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this?
I tried going to project->index->rebuild or Re-reslove unresloved inclusion
I tried cleaning, I tried rebuliding... 
And I didn't change anything in the include settings...

Comment: Did you try closing Eclipse?

Comment: You need to specify *filesystem path* for the libraries.

Comment: No you don't, at least not in the include directive and especially not for the library as we are talking about the include path. <string> should be generally resolved by the compiler because it's in the stdlib.

Comment: @stefan i even tried rebooting my PC.
Robin - I agree, but was that just a comment or do u also have a suggestion?